# BindableRadioGroup in Xamarin iOS project

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working in a Xamarin project.
Previously the project was only Android, now I need to include also the iOS version of the same application.
In a page of my application there is a dynamic list of radio button. The component that I used is a BindableRadioGroup of the XLabs.Forms package.

This is the tag in the xaml page:

```
<ScrollView  Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="250">
    <controls:BindableRadioGroup SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedAnomaly, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding AnomalyList, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ScrollView>
```

The code in my ViewModel:

```
public DomainFEModel SelectedAnomalyDomain
        {
            get { return _selectedAnomalyDomain; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedAnomalyDomain, value); }
        }

public ObservableCollection<string> AnomalyList
        {
            get { return _anomalyList; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _anomalyList, value); }
        }
```

This is the front-end model:

```
public class DomainFEModel : FEModel
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}
```

The list is dynamically populated from the database.
All works correctly in the Android version:

[image: Android version]

But it doesn't work in the iOS version:

[image: iOS version]

I can't select an element of the list.
How I can solve this problem in iOS? There is another way to create this radio button dynamic list that can work both in Android and iOS version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with an update of Xamarin.Forms to version 5.0.0.2012 and I changed the code with the introduction of the "selected" attribute in the DomainFEModel.
This is my new code:

XAML:

```
<ScrollView  Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="300">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Anomalies}" SelectionMode="Single" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="White">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <RadioButton Content="{Binding description}" Value="{Binding key}" IsChecked="{Binding selected}" GroupName="Anomalies" BackgroundColor="White" TextColor="Black" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollView>
```

Variables in ViewModel:

```
private DomainFEModel[] _anomalies;
    
 public DomainFEModel[] Anomalies
     {
         get { return _anomalies; }
         set { SetProperty(ref _anomalies, value); }
     }
```

DomainFEModel class:

```
 public class DomainFEModel : FEModel
     {
         public string key { get; set; }
         public string description { get; set; }    
         public bool selected { get; set; } = false;
    
     }
```

Method to retrieve the selected element:

```
private DomainFEModel getSelectedAnomaly()
         {
             try
             {
                 for (int i = 0; i < Anomalies.Length; i++)
                 {
                     if (Anomalies[i].selected)
                     {
                         return Anomalies[i];
                     }
                 }
                 return null;
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {                
                 return null;
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, Xamarin has released the new `RadioButton` control. Try to update the Xamarin.Forms to the latest version, and you can check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton) and the class documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.radiobutton?view=xamarin-forms).

To add RadioButtons dynamiclly, you can create them as follows:

```
// create 5 radiobuttons
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
    radioButton.Content = $"Content{i}";
    if (i == 1) // check the 2rd one
        radioButton.IsChecked = true;
    MyLayout.Children.Add(radioButton);
}
```